# openCV - Canny operator: Detect only falling gradientslope possible?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi, canny-operator

This is my [input image](https://ibb.co/5BG57QN)

This is my [output image](https://ibb.co/mBwJ3X3) after the Canny operator.

As you can see it gives me 4 white lines which is correct.
But I need only 2.
Is it possible to get from the Canny operator only the edges where the gradient/slope is only falling or rising? In this way I could get in  only 2 lines is this correct?

Right now the Canny operator gives me falling and rising slopes I need one of them.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What do you consider raising or falling slope? That totally depends on the direction of travel. Going to work I go down a hill, coming back home I go up. It’s the same edge of the hill. So you need to define a direction. Maybe raising along the x-axis? Canny detects edges, not their direction. You need a gradient operator.

Comment: As Cris says, maybe consider a Sobel filter https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html